# S3 event notification body content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I've configured an event notification on an AWS s3 bucket, putting a message on an SQS queue.

The body of that event contains an array of records.
I would like to understand in which conditions there are multiple records in the body.

Is it when we upload files immediately after each other?
Or only when uploading multiple files at once?

So is this generated on a time basis, collecting all the requests in X amount of time and sending a message to SQS, or is it a separate event for each request to the bucket?

Comment: I would suggest you ensure you can handle however many events there may be in the Records array, regardless of whether there always appears to be one. Because unless it's documented that there will always be only one (in which case, why have an array?), then there's nothing to stop current behaviour from changing in the future. I suspect this is undocumented behaviour, so you may know from experience that it's always 1 unless x scenario, but that behaviour could change in the future.

Answer (score -2):

There are different ways you can find S3 Event message structure;

1. [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html) is document from AWS with [Event message structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html).

To get specific S3 Event message structure, you can go for one of following practical approach;

2. You can enable [AWS cloud-trail logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-request-identification.html). Then, perform some events on related AWS S3 bucket, afterwards view S3 events using the [AWS cloudtrail Event history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events-console.html) or Insights based on your AWS S3 bucket.
3. Use a simple [AWS lambda mapped to your AWS S3 events](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudtrail-update-capture-and-process-amazon-s3-object-level-api-activity/), which will just print the AWS S3 events associated with your S3 bucket.